# Recommended Service Account role?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud Platform for first time to get data from Google Analytics Reporting, where I authenticate via Service Account from my web-app. All I do is get data from Analytics and display it in charts, so I'm curious about which role should I define in the service account key.

I'm currently selecting `Role > Project > Owner` but I feel is so a high-level role for this use.

The project has 3 APIs enabled: `Google Analytics Reporting API`, `Analytics API` and `Google Maps JavaScript API`.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the *Google Cloud IAM* Docs ([Understanding Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) specifically) I think the best role for my needs is ***Viewer***.

Comment: For that specific task of yours, assigning the "Viewer" role is the best option. On an additional note, there is a beta release on creating a "[Custom Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles)" (i.e you will be able to create and manage roles as per your requirement) as well. You can check [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles) help center article for more details regarding this and can suggest your own [feedback](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeANmV06_CnLqN-BWz1njdw4Sn6NMSO4lh9tX7QtohArmr6Hw/viewform) there.